# Rotate a specific window not the entire display Mac

Tags: macos, display

I know how to rotate the main display and external displays using system settings in macOS.

However I want to only rotate the window an application appears in not the entire display. There are no controls to do this that natively exist in the application.

Is there anyway to achieve this via the OS or a third party application?

Comment: There's certainly no way in the OS to do this. Can you explain about why you want this window to be rotated? Which application is it? (Surely any text will be upside-down/sideways!)